# Doing live edits with datatables in JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I currently have the code below that gives me 2 perfectly working datatables. They are attached to a select box which shows/hides one table depending on the selection. Everything works perfectly right now, but I need to try and achieve a new task with these tables:

I've never seen this exactly, but I need an option to 'drop' or remove columns from my tables with some type of selection option, but this can only remove the columns from the current view of the tables. This is for comparing and QA, so I may be looking at the table and need to drop 5 unnecessary columns from the view, but not the database. So, if I refresh the page, the table is back to normal.

Any ideas here are greatly appreciated:

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
        $('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();
        $('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');
        $(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
            var table = $(this).val();
            $('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
            $('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
        });
        $("#select-tables").trigger("change");
    });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: This is really too broad. I guess there is a lot of SO'ers who could answer, but the answers would be too dedicated, not helping anyone in the future... Hire a programmer instead. For 1) there is many answers here on SO, for 2) use the [colvis](https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis) button plugin along with x dummy columns.

Comment: Well, I solved the Editor plugin issue to fully delete rows (client side and server side) but the main issue is removing/dropping columns on the client side. I haven't found many options to do that with JQuery datatables or the editor plugin and I also don't see that as being very broad or dedicated for me. I feel like that answer alone might help in the future and I've edited my question for that issue alone. I'm really just trying to get some assistance with Datatables which I've never used, but I can't hire a programmer since I'm doing the programming myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually was able to answer this question, in a different way, with the use of
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html